# Can't get Web Scraped Table to populate multiple cells VBA

Tags: vba, web-scraping, html-table

I am trying to scrape a table from a website via VBA. I am able to gather all the data from the table however I am only able to get it to populate a single cell, rather than break out the information as formatted on the website. Essentially the data should be in four columns and then go down as many rows as there is data. I know I'm missing something simple here and I just can't put my finger on it. Help please! coding is below:

```
Sub WebScrape()

Dim objIE As InternetExplore'

Dim ele As Object
Dim y As Integer
objIE.navigate "http://www.uscfinvestments.com/holdings/usci"
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

y = 1
For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementById("holdingsTableDiv").getElementsByTagName("table")
    Debug.Print ele.textContent
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).Value = ele.Children(0).textContent
Next
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: You're never incrementing your `y` counter, so every loop iteration is overwriting the value written by the previous one.

Comment: Does the correct/complete content show up in the immediate pane (from these `Debug.Print` statements)?

Comment: Also, you're only ever writing to column A. Might want to iterate `tr` elements to know when to increment `y`.

Comment: yes, all the information is complete but only shows up in A1.

Comment: As Mathieu Guindon said, it only shows up in A1 because your only write assignment is `Range("A" & y)`, which is hard coded to column `A`, and you set the value of `y` to 1 and then never change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show a number of methods below. Personally, I prefer the last which uses an API.

---

**Using clipboard:**

A nice easy way, if you want to appear as on page, is to simply copy the table to clipboard and paste

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, hTable As Object, clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://www.uscfinvestments.com/holdings/usci"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set hTable = .document.getElementById("holdingsTableID")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While hTable Is Nothing

        If Not hTable Is Nothing Then
            clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
            clipboard.PutInClipboard
            ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
        End If
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Looping table:**

If you want to loop rows and columns of a table then you can use row class name and row number to determine how to write out

```
Option Explicit  
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, hTable As Object, ws As Worksheet, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://www.uscfinvestments.com/holdings/usci"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set hTable = .document.getElementById("holdingsTableID")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While hTable Is Nothing

        If Not hTable Is Nothing Then
            WriteTable hTable, 1, ws
        End If
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tRow As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long, th As Object
    r = startRow
    With ws
        For Each tRow In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            c = 1
            If r = startRow Or tRow.className = "subHeader" Then
                For Each th In tRow.getElementsByTagName("th")
                    .Cells(r, c) = th.innerText
                    c = c + 1
                Next
            Else
                For Each td In tRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                    .Cells(r, c).Value = td.innerText
                    c = c + 1
                Next td
            End If
            r = r + 1
        Next tRow
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**API:**

There is an  API which serves the data in a json format

```
https://cssecure.alpsinc.com/api/v1//holding/usci
```

It requires authentication. I am using [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to parse the json returned. After downloading and adding the .bas you need to go VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetValues()
    Dim json As Object, authorization As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.uscfinvestments.com/uscfinvestments-template/assets/javascript/api_key.php", False
        .send
        authorization = Split(Split(.responseText, "'")(1), "'")(0)
        .Open "GET", "https://cssecure.alpsinc.com/api/v1//holding/usci", False
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", authorization
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
    End With
    Dim arr(), headers(), item As Object, r As Long
    headers = Array("Security", "Quantity", "Price", "Market Value")
    r = 1
    ReDim arr(1 To json.Count, 1 To 4)
    For Each item In json
        arr(r, 1) = item("name")
        arr(r, 2) = item("shares")
        Dim test As String
        If IsNull(item("contractprice")) Then
           arr(r, 3) = item("settlementprice")
        Else
            arr(r, 3) = item("contractprice")
        End If
        arr(r, 4) = item("marketvalue")
        r = r + 1
    Next
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Definitely use an API when there is one. Web-scraping content off HTTP requests when there's an API might be a breach of TOS (web-scraping contents can also be a breach of TOS regardless of whether there's an API or not, though)

Comment: Thanks @QHarr! That was perfect! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing much to add here. QHarr has already covered them. I used hardcoded delay instead of explicit wait to make the script less verbose.

```
Sub GetContent()
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument, elem As Object, tRow As Object, C&, R&

    With New InternetExplorer
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "http://www.uscfinvestments.com/holdings/usci"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .Document
    End With

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03") 'make it 05 if it fails somehow

    For Each elem In Html.getElementById("holdingsTableID").Rows
        For Each tRow In elem.Cells
            C = C + 1: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(R + 1, C) = tRow.innerText
        Next tRow
        C = 0: R = R + 1
    Next elem
End Sub
```